When pasting a file with the same name, how to automatically create a copy of the old file instead of overwriting the file?
When pasting a file with the same name, how to automatically create a copy of the old file instead of overwriting the file?
(The pop up window only allows me to overwrite or cancel the action, and I have to manually create a copy of every old files that have same names.)

(Or, move the old file to recycle bin.)

(A XYplorer script could help, but it will be better if there is any other easier method.)



Regrettably, built-in Windows utilities such as Robocopy do not provide for renaming files automatically when a duplicate filename exists. However, a PowerShell script can be used to copy and rename duplicates.
The following script from SumTips should meet your needs. If a file with the same name exists in the destination, "it would rename the duplicate file by appending a number – which is automatically incremented – before the extension."
function fcopy ($SourceDir,$DestinationDir)
{
    Get-ChildItem $SourceDir -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -eq $false } | ForEach-Object ($_) {
        $SourceFile = $_.FullName
        $DestinationFile = $DestinationDir + $_
        if (Test-Path $DestinationFile) {
            $i = 0
            while (Test-Path $DestinationFile) {
                $i += 1
                $DestinationFile = $DestinationDir + $_.basename + $i + $_.extension
            }
        } else {
            Copy-Item -Path $SourceFile -Destination $DestinationFile -Verbose -Force
        }
        Copy-Item -Path $SourceFile -Destination $DestinationFile -Verbose -Force
    }
}

fcopy -SourceDir "C:\Source\Directory\" -DestinationDir "C:\Destination\Directory\"

Caveat
This has not been tested. Also, it renames the file being copied, not the preexisting file in the folder.
